# Filling memory with random bytes - C/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, random, fill

I'm using CommonCrypto for encryption in Objective-C (AES256) and I'd like to provide an IV (initialization vector) for a more secure encryption. I'm currently doing this:

```
const void* iv = malloc(kCCBlockSizeAES128);
// EDIT:
//if (!iv) {
//    iv = NULL;
//}
```

and then I create the cryptor object:

```
CCCryptorRef cryptor;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCryptorCreate(operation, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                                  keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                                  iv,
                                                  &cryptor);
```

The problem is that encryption this way seems to fail (sad face...). I mean: it encrypts with no apparent problem, but it decrypts data different than the original. I though this would work because when you `malloc()` memory, it is not written all to zeros, it is random. I also tried writing random values myself but my C background is failing really hard. If there is a function (like `bzero`) that writes random bytes please tell me.

I also tried doing something like this:

```
char* iv = malloc(kCCBlockSizeAES128);
int i;
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < kCCBlockSizeAES128; i++) {
    iv[i] = (char)rand()%256;
}
```

Ohh, by the way, I realise this must be a very nooby question :)

In the end all I want is something like `const void* iv = malloc(kCCBlockSizeAES128)` that after some operations I am sure it's data is completely random. Any ideas on that?

PS: I only provided the crypto/Objective-C background so you know what I need this for. I think that won't influence a thing. kCCBlockSizeAES128 = 16 (90% sure :)

### EDIT:

Allright! After *some* deugging I'm happy to announce that the problem I was having with the encryption & decryption was due to a bug in another part of my program I have now solved. So all I need to figure now is how to fill the iv with random bytes. Some options:

- Use malloc(), which returns junk, not random bytes -> potentially insecure **(?)**
- Use arc4random_buf(), which is exactly what I want except it only works 10.7+ and my mac is 10.6.6 (plus I want to support 10.6)
- Something else I haven't considered...? **<-- help here!**

### EDIT 2:

Allright! After filling the iv with some test data (all zeros, all ones, etc) and *some more* deugging I'm **NOT** happy to announce that ccrypto doesn't seem to be working in some conditions. I'll explain how:

Whenever I feed the crypto a zeroed iv or NULL (same thing for crypto) it works. For example, this works well when encrypting and decrypting:

```
uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < kCCBlockSizeAES128; i++) {
    iv[i] = 0x0; // I know this is the same as doing: memset((void *)iv, 0x0, (size_t)sizeof(iv));
}

CCCryptorRef cryptor;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCryptorCreate(operation, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                              kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                              (const void *)keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                              iv,
                                              &cryptor);
```

**BUT** when I feed him a iv in which at least ONE of it's bytes is NOT zero, encryption/decryption do not provide errors but decrypting doesn't yield the original data. For example, this...

```
uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < kCCBlockSizeAES128; i++) {
    iv[i] = 0x1;
}
```

or for completely random data...

```
uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < kCCBlockSizeAES128; i++) {
    iv[i] = arc4random() % 256;
}
```

...won't work.

I do not understand this logic one single bit... Any ideas?

Comment: Comment: `if (!iv) { iv = NULL; }` makes no sens.

Comment: @Mat I did that because if you provide the crpypto with NULL, it will create an IV itself with all zeros always. When I can't create an IV I let crypto create a zeroed IV. Otherwise I want to have a random IV.

Comment: Your post is very vague: "seems to fail"? Make sure it is failing. Also that crypto function should work regardless of the contents of the IV - might not be secure, but will work. So your problem is probably elsewhere. Please describe in more detail _what_ is not working and how it's failing. (The statement inside the `if` block will only run if `!iv` is true, which only happens if `iv == null`...)

Comment: @Mat Well, I say it seems to fail because I encrypt a file with no problems, but when I decrypt it it's info is different than the original file. You're right, this is pretty vague. I'll continue debugging. If I find something I'll let you know. About if (!iv) {...}, I see what you mean now :)

Comment: @Mat I have updated my question, could you please check it again?

Comment: Are you using the same IV for decryption?

Comment: No, I'm not. I have tried giving crypto NULL (zeroed IV) on decryption and also a random IV using the methods above. None worked. Should I? If so, how? Am I supposed to save it with the file or something?

Comment: If you don't know whether you should be using the same IV or not, you've got to go back to studying your crypto algorithm and cipher mode of operation. You really _need_ to understand that to be able to implement encryption.

Comment: @Mat Wow, yes, of course. You're completely right. I hope I'm not missing anything else. I had no idea I had to use the same iv. Thank you very much for pointing that out. Now I just need to figure out the inner workings for the first 16 bytes being the IV. Thanks, I guess I know how to do it now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `arc4random_buf` to fill the buffer with random data:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
arc4random_buf(&iv, kCCBlockSizeAES128);
```

---

Also, the memory block returned by `malloc` (as with any uninitialised memory) is filled with *garbage*. You should not assume that it will be filled with *anything*, especially not cryptographically useful random numbers.

Comment: The compiler can't find the function `arc4random_buf`, even with the import statement. Is it arc4random_addrandom() or something like it?

Comment: Make sure you're compiling against the Mac OS X 10.7 or iOS 4.3 (or higher) SDK.

Comment: Well, I'm compiling with Mac OS 10.6... But will arc4random_addrandom() do?

Comment: No, `arc4random_addrandom` seeds the RNG, it doesn't produce any values.

Comment: this might be a dumb question, why are u passing &iv to arc4random_buf rather than just iv? I thought iv is already a pointer and we just need to put random data in where iv is pointing to...

Comment: In this case, `iv` and `&iv` are equivalent. `&iv` is the address of the array, and `iv` decays into a pointer to the first element of the array when passed to a function (which are both the same). [The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html) has a more detailed explanation of this.

Comment: isn't &iv the address containing the value of the pointer? I think you should pass iv and not &iv