# Numerical Data from any iOS API

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, calayer

I'm looking for any iOS Library that supplies numerical data.

My menus show a few animated graphs in the background, right now I use mostly random data.
Now I'm looking for any kind of dynamic data one can read from the iOS Api, be creative, what would you use?

1. Obviously I already use the Accelerometer input
2. FFT of Mic input is an option, but then the user will get the "Allow this app access to the microphone" which would be weird because I don't use the mic anywhere else

EDIT: Also performance should not exceed 5% of cpu load. Right now with my random data I use BLAS so it really doesn't affect the rest of the app. It's just for aesthetic sugar.

Comment: A music, image file.

Comment: An image file or music would have to be entered or would always be the same, wouldn't it?
Unless I use the latest saved file or the like, but the saved file sin my app won't change that much.

Comment: ...or it can be downloaded from some place that you can easily update (Google drive, Dropbox, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a lot of random data at once is using [`Security.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security) [Randomization Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/randomization_services) to read `/dev/random`:

```
int vectorSize = 8192;
uint8_t dataVector[vectorSize];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, vectorSize, dataVector);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)dataVector length:vectorSize];
```

Comment: Uhh, thats nice, I never heard of that. Maybe I can vectorize my BoxMuller and use the random data in place of the arc4random calls..

Comment: Sadly, `SecRandomCopyBytes` may fail (an example return code could be `errSecDiskFull`). I wonder if [a simple call to `arc4random_buf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972691/1033581) isn't simply better.